# Kendo grid displaying multiple page

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

This is my code for kendo the page is displaying multiple time given in 
i tried every this but its still not working please suggest me what to do to solve this problem. picture[image].And validation message is also not showing its validation but not displaying message

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#production-grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ProductAttributeList", "Production"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SettingAdd", "Production"))",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json"
                    //data: addAntiForgeryToken
                },
                update: {
                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SettingUpdate", "Production"))",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
                //data: addAntiForgeryToken
            },
                destroy: {
                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SettingDelete", "Production"))",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
                    //data: addAntiForgeryToken
                },
            parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
                if (operation != "read") {
                    return data;
                } else {
                    //for some reasons only such "Filter" data be parsed
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            }
        },
            schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total",
            errors: "Errors",
            model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                    Image: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                    IteamId: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                    ProductId: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                    UserName: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                    FoundInProductName: { false: true, type: "string" },
                    FoundInProductDescription: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                    TaggedKeyword: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                    TaggedComment: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                    AttributeName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    Comment: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    ShelfID: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    ShelfName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    ProductType: { editable: true, type: "string",
                                validation: { required: true , message: "Product Type is required" } } ,
                        Remark: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        Id: { editable: false, type: "number" }
                    }
            }
            },
        requestEnd: function(e) {
            if (e.type == "create" || e.type == "update") {
                this.read();
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
            // Cancel the changes
            this.cancelChanges();
        },
        pageSize: 50,
            serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
        },
        pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes:[ 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]
        },
        scrollable: true,
            editable: true,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                headerTemplate: "<input id='mastercheckbox' type='checkbox'/>",
                headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center" },
                attributes: { style: "text-align:center" },
                template: "<input type='checkbox' value='#=Id#' class='checkboxGroups'/>",
                width: 50
            },{
                field: "Image",
                title: "Image",
                width: 300
            },{
                field: "IteamId",
                title: "IteamId",
                width: 300
            },
        {
            field: "ProductId",
            title: "ProductId",
            width: 300
        }, {
            field: "UserName",
            title: "UserName",
            width: 300
        }, {
            field: "FoundInProductName",
            title: "Keyword found(PN)",
            width: 300
        }, {
            field: "FoundInProductDescription",
            title: "Keyword found(PD)",
            width: 300
        }, {
            field: "TaggedKeyword",
            title: "Tagged Keyword",
            width: 300
        }, {
            field: "TaggedComment",
            title: "Tagged Comment",
            width: 300
        },
        {
            field: "AttributeName",
            title: "Attribute Name(the attribute which is worked upon- E.g. Color)",
            width: 300
        },
        {
            field: "Comment",
            title: "Comment",
            editor: CommentTypeDropDownEditor,
            template: "#:Comment#",
            width: 300
        },
        {
            field: "ShelfID",
            title: "Suggested Shelf ID",
            width: 300
        },
        {
            field: "ShelfName",
            title: "Suggested Shelf Name",
            width: 300
        },
        {
            field: "ProductType",
            title: "Product Type",
            width: 300
        },
        {
            field: "Remark",
            title: "Remarks (Free Text)",
            width: 300
        }
        ]
        });
```

i can able to fingure out what the issue and validation message is also not displaying